# How can I get time from specific timezone?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a timezone and I do:

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00”);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

How can I get a `DateTime` object with the correct time from this timezone?
If I do `c.getTime()` I get the current time and not *that* timezone’s time.
Doing

```
String time = String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+
            String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+
.                   String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.SECOND))+":"+
    .           String.format("%03d" , c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

I get the expected time but I can not create a valid `DateTime` object from this string.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Which version of Java do you use? 8 or less?

Comment: You mentioned jodatime as a tag; do you actually use it? Your code only relies on the old API

Comment: If you want a `DateTime` to have a time zone, you need to set that `DateTime` with that time zone using `DateTimeZone`. Why are you mixing `java.util.Calendar` with Joda-Time?

Comment: @fge:Yes I can use it if there is a solution with the JodaTime.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I am using code I found searching. Is there a better/another way?

Comment: Yes. Read the Joda Time documentation, they have several guides, play around with it and learn how to use it. Don't use code from the Internet unless you fully understand what it does. You should understand what a `DateTime` represents and how. You should also format times using specific date/time formatters (available in Joda), rather than `String.format`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// GMT-5
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5:00"));
String strDate = df.format(date);
System.out.println("Date and time in GMT-5: " + strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility to obtain and print time with time zone included:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class TestDate {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        String dateString = df.format(date);

        System.out.println(dateString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful see this link

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
String time = String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+
            String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+
.                   String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.SECOND))+":"+
    .           String.format("%03d" , c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DateTime.WithZone` method

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00");
    DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timeZone);
    System.out.println(timeZone);
    System.out.println(dateTimeZone);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    DateTime dtLondon = dt.withZone(dateTimeZone);
    System.out.println(dtLondon);
```

Comment: I don’t have the info for the `forId` part

Comment: ok, I get it, taak a look at the updated answer please...@Jim